# An error occurred while collecting items to be installed: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.sdk,4.2.0.v201206081400

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno, xtext

I am trying to export an Xtext project as an Eclipse Product. The launch configuration works flawlessly if launched from within Eclipse, but I am unable to export it to make a self-contained product. I get:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
 session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
 Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.sdk,4.2.0.v201206081400.

org.eclipse.sdk-4.2.0.v201206081400 is already imported as project in the workspace. I'm trying to export using "all workspace and enabled target plugin" rather than selecting the plugins one by one.

I'm on Linux 64bit (Sabayon).

Comment: Check your target platform.

Comment: for which OSs are you trying to build the product?

Answer (score 0):

Building for the running platform should not be a problem. Did you create a product and try to run that in a eclipse? I suspect you are running the project as an eclipse instance not from the product project

Can you make sure you change the splash screen on your product and run it in eclipse?

- If you see the splash screen you changed and it works, it should be
  working when you try to build the  product.
- If not you need to check what is missing between run config and the
  product configuration.